# UNION on 2 queries with one table difference

Tags: sql

Id like to merge or UNION two queries

The query result columns are of the same type and size but one table differs in each. Can it be done?

The first is from the Absent table the second form the Attend Table. These two tables are basically exactly the same( dont know why there has to be 2 tables if 1 would have sufficed)

```
SELECT DISTINCT dmg.dmg_FirstName,
        dmg.dmg_Surname,
        lnk.lnk_ID,
        dlk.dlk_AssessDate,
        dmg.dmg_Sex,
        trn.ScotHealthboard
FROM    DAILY_LINK dlk
JOIN    Absent ab ON ab.ScotRefID = dlk.dlk_ID
JOIN    Link lnk ON lnk.lnk_ID = ab.Person_ID
JOIN    Demographic dmg ON dmg.dmg_ID = lnk.lnk_dmgID
JOIN    Training trn ON trn.Trn_ID = ab.Training_ID
WHERE   dlk.dlk_AssessDate >= '2015/01/01' AND dlk.dlk_AssessDate <= '2015/12/01';
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT dmg.dmg_FirstName,
        dmg.dmg_Surname,
        lnk.lnk_ID,
        dlk.dlk_AssessDate,
        dmg.dmg_Sex,
        trn.ScotHealthboard
FROM    DAILY_LINK dlk
JOIN    Attend at ON at.ScotRefID = dlk.dlk_ID
JOIN    Link lnk ON lnk.lnk_ID = at.Person_ID
JOIN    Demographic dmg ON dmg.dmg_ID = lnk.lnk_dmgID
JOIN    Training trn ON trn.Trn_ID = at.Training_ID
WHERE   dlk.dlk_AssessDate >= '2015/01/01' AND dlk.dlk_AssessDate <= '2015/12/01';
```

Comment: This looks ok, what isn't working?

Comment: Did you try? On first glance I don't see a problem with your query. Do you get an error when you execute?

Comment: Just gives a "GENERAL ERROR".

Comment: Please specify database system

Comment: If I execute them individually they work fine, but as soon as I add the UNION it fails. Could it be the DISTINCT that throws it off?

Comment: Database system is a 4D (4th Dimension) sql DB. So I think ist a less powerfull version of mySQL.

Comment: Aren't these two queries exactly the same? Would it not be sufficient with just one of them? Have you tried just using one?

Comment: @mortb. nope look closely at line number 8 and 21

Comment: @morne: oh, sorry!

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT since the UNION will remove all duplicates anyway.

Comment: Is there really no other clue besides general error? I suggest you first use just _one_ of the columns from each table and see if that works. Yes? OK try the next one and continue till you find the offending column (if indeed that is the issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suspect the `;` just before `union` is causing an error. If you remove it, it should run fine.

```
SELECT DISTINCT dmg.dmg_FirstName,
        dmg.dmg_Surname,
        lnk.lnk_ID,
        dlk.dlk_AssessDate,
        dmg.dmg_Sex,
        trn.ScotHealthboard
FROM    DAILY_LINK dlk
JOIN    Absent ab ON ab.ScotRefID = dlk.dlk_ID
JOIN    Link lnk ON lnk.lnk_ID = ab.Person_ID
JOIN    Demographic dmg ON dmg.dmg_ID = lnk.lnk_dmgID
JOIN    Training trn ON trn.Trn_ID = ab.Training_ID
WHERE   dlk.dlk_AssessDate >= '2015/01/01' AND dlk.dlk_AssessDate <= '2015/12/01'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT dmg.dmg_FirstName,
        dmg.dmg_Surname,
        lnk.lnk_ID,
        dlk.dlk_AssessDate,
        dmg.dmg_Sex,
        trn.ScotHealthboard
FROM    DAILY_LINK dlk
JOIN    Attend at ON at.ScotRefID = dlk.dlk_ID
JOIN    Link lnk ON lnk.lnk_ID = at.Person_ID
JOIN    Demographic dmg ON dmg.dmg_ID = lnk.lnk_dmgID
JOIN    Training trn ON trn.Trn_ID = at.Training_ID
WHERE   dlk.dlk_AssessDate >= '2015/01/01' AND dlk.dlk_AssessDate <= '2015/12/01';
```

Comment: Sorry @Honey Badger. but it failed aswell.

Comment: I'm not familiar with you databaase system, but could it be it's confused if you use the same aliases?

Comment: ah, good point. let me try that. Good suggestion mate, thanks.

Comment: @HoneyBadger. Thanks for the help and all. That query as you wrote it is correct, but 4D or 4th Dimension ( my DB engine) does not support UNION and thats why it fails. Seems like its a very limited version of MySQL that they included in the engine. Will mark you anyway cus it is correct.

Comment: @morne, Glad I could help, well, sort of anyway. I guess it means what you need is not possible with your database. Shame you've been given such a basic database....